# \setparsizes and List of Algorithms

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, paragraphs, line-spacing, algorithm2e

For some reason, in my work I have to reset the spacing of paragraphs with `\setparsizes`.
This works quite well in the main part of the skript. But unfortunatley, it also effects the list of algorithms. There is some extra space added between the entries, even all algorithms are in the same chapter.

[image]

I dont want to have this behaviour. It is also strange, because the `\setparsizes`-command does neither effect the list of tables nor the table of contents, but only the list of algorithms.

How can I suppress the extra spacing in the indices, especially in the list of algorithms, while keeping the `\setparsizes`-command for the main content? Maybe some grouping?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[algochapter]{algorithm2e}

% This line causes the problem.
\setparsizes{0pt}{1\baselineskip plus .6\baselineskip minus .4\baselineskip}{0pt plus 1fil}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoftables
\listofalgorithms
\endgroup

% Some useless content
\chapter{First Chapter}
\begin{table}\caption{First table}\end{table}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Section 2.1}
\begin{table}\caption{Second table}\end{table}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{First algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\section{Section 2.2}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{Second algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.1}
\begin{table}\caption{Third table}\end{table}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{Third algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{table}\caption{Fourth table}\end{table}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{Fourth algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.2}
\section{Section 2.3}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use

```latex
\addtotoclist[float]{loa}
\renewcommand*\listofalgorithms{\listoftoc[\listalgorithmcfname]{loa}}
```

Then `\listofalgorithms` is under controll of KOMA-Script package `tocbasic`.

To ensure that the same indent and number width is used:

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[level:=figure,indent:=figure,numwidth:=figure]{tocline}{algocf}
```

Note, that the syntax `level:` etc. needs at least KOMA-Script version 3.27.

I would also suggest to restore the chapter definition of KOMA-Script using

```latex
\RedeclareSectionCommand{chapter}
```

If LoF, LoT and LoA should really be chapters without page break before them, you could use

```latex
\doforeachtocfile[float]{\BeforeTOCHead[#1]{\let\clearpage\relax}}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}[2019/10/12]
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[algochapter]{algorithm2e}

\RedeclareSectionCommand{chapter}
\addtotoclist[float]{loa}
\renewcommand*\listofalgorithms{\listoftoc[\listalgorithmcfname]{loa}}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[level:=figure,indent:=figure,numwidth:=figure]{tocline}{algocf}

\doforeachtocfile[float]{\BeforeTOCHead[#1]{\let\clearpage\relax}}

% This line causes the problem.
\setparsizes{0pt}{1\baselineskip plus .6\baselineskip minus .4\baselineskip}{0pt plus 1fil}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listofalgorithms

% Some useless content
\chapter{First Chapter}
\begin{table}\caption{First table}\end{table}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Section 2.1}
\begin{table}\caption{Second table}\end{table}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{First algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\section{Section 2.2}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{Second algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.1}
\begin{table}\caption{Third table}\end{table}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{Third algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{table}\caption{Fourth table}\end{table}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{Fourth algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.2}
\section{Section 2.3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I would use option `listof=leveldown`. Then the LoF, LoT, LoA etc. are sections. So there would be no need to redefine `\clearpage`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[listof=leveldown]{scrreprt}[2019/10/12]
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[algochapter]{algorithm2e}

\RedeclareSectionCommand{chapter}
\addtotoclist[float]{loa}
\renewcommand*\listofalgorithms{\listoftoc[\listalgorithmcfname]{loa}}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[level:=figure,indent:=figure,numwidth:=figure]{tocline}{algocf}


% This line causes the problem.
\setparsizes{0pt}{1\baselineskip plus .6\baselineskip minus .4\baselineskip}{0pt plus 1fil}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listofalgorithms

% Some useless content
\chapter{First Chapter}
\begin{table}\caption{First table}\end{table}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Section 2.1}
\begin{table}\caption{Second table}\end{table}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{First algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\section{Section 2.2}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{Second algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.1}
\begin{table}\caption{Third table}\end{table}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{Third algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{table}\caption{Fourth table}\end{table}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{Fourth algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.2}
\section{Section 2.3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! :) But why the command `\addtotoclist[float]{loa}` is needed? It is also working without that line. – Till now, I didnt realize that there is some deviation in the indent^^ Thanks a lot!

Comment: `\addtotoclist[float]{loa}` is needed, if the list of algorithms should take care of values of option `listof=...`, eg `listof=leveldown` or `listof=totoc` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You may teach `\listofalgorithms` (actually the internal version `\listofalgocfs`) to use `\tocbasic@starttoc` (specific for `scrreprt`) instead of the standard `\@starttoc` command.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\listofalgocfs}{\@starttoc}{\tocbasic@starttoc}{}{}
\makeatother

% This line causes the problem.
\setparsizes{0pt}{1\baselineskip plus .6\baselineskip minus .4\baselineskip}{0pt plus 1fil}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoftables
\listofalgorithms
\endgroup

% Some useless content
\chapter{First Chapter}
\begin{table}\caption{First table}\end{table}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Section 2.1}
\begin{table}\caption{Second table}\end{table}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{First algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\section{Section 2.2}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{Second algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.1}
\begin{table}\caption{Third table}\end{table}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{Third algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\begin{table}\caption{Fourth table}\end{table}
\begin{algorithm}\caption{Fourth algorithm}\end{algorithm}
\subsection{Subsection 2.2.2}
\section{Section 2.3}

\end{document}
```

[image]